# My essay has been plagarized in a journal article - what to do?

Tags: plagiarism

I have an essay online on a dense philosophical text. One sentence of my paraphrasing or interpretation of this text has been copied verbatim in a now-published journal article. In that article, the sentence is attributed to the original author of the philosophical text, not to my essay. The article was published this year; my text was written over five years ago.

This upsets me because

1. I believe I have been plagiarized
2. The authors are asserting my paraphrasing and interpretation of the text as their own, and in the process skipping the work of interpreting the original text, along with misleading their readers. If the authors want to use the text to support their argument, they should paraphrase it themselves, or quote directly (and who knows, my interpretation could be *wildly off!*).

Regardless, can any one advise on the best way to report or address this, or what I should expect if I do so?

Comment: How many words in the sentence that you believe it was plagiarized?

Comment: @qsp: It could still be that the idea itself was plagiarized, regardless of the word count.  Harder to prove, perhaps, but still potentially plagiarism nonetheless.

Comment: @tonysdg: if my understanding is correct, the OP only paraphrased a text, so there is nothing new in the idea. If the sentence is too short, perhaps there is not many way to paraphrase that text, and hence it could just be an accident. Therefore, although lifting a sentence verbatim is plagiarism, this case may be too trivial and unprovable if the sentence is too short.

Comment: @qsp It's 26 words, but there is a key idea conveyed there, which is a lot of why I think it was lifted in the first place. I think if someone were to read the sentence they would agree it's been copied intentionally.

Comment: "*In that article, the sentence is attributed to the original author of the philosophical text ... The authors are asserting my paraphrasing and interpretation of the text as their own*". I'm confused.

Comment: In other words, the authors have lifted my sentence verbatim, which is partially an interpretation, and simply footnoted it to the original philosopher.

Comment: @wxs: Are you *certain* your own essay did not make it seem like you are quoting the original text? Maybe this was just a mistake made by the article's author? (I'm not saying this is okay, quoting a text without checking if what they are quoting is in the actual text is sloppy, at the very least, but, as they say, never attribute to malice that which can be explained by mere incompetence and/or laziness. Not the first time around, anyway. ;))

Comment: @tomasz That's a good point. Of course I can't know if it was an honest mistake or misunderstanding by the article author, but I can say that there are direct quotes (with the page number cited) in my essay. I would argue the authors should know when I'm using my own words or the philosopher's.

Comment: @wxs: Perhaps you could simply contact the authors and clear up the whole mess without going to the editor over their heads? I don't have any directly relevant experience, but I believe that it's generally better to solve problems cordially, without involving higher authority, whenever it's possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Contact the editor of the journal, present your suspicions, and be prepared to submit evidence supporting your claim.

Comment: I'm not so sure that a journal editor would, or even should, proceed with plagiarism charges on the basis of a single sentence.

Comment: With one sentence, there is a high probability that this is just how the author wrote it himself, without copying the poster. For example, it would be quite possible that someone typed an answer _identical_ to tonysdg's one sentence. No copying, no plagiarism. And then there is the question whether anyone would care if one sentence is copied without attribution.